# How to download Xcode 13 if the App Store is not accessible?

Tags: xcode, mac-appstore, developer-program

My organisation is blocking access to the App Store for security reasons, so I can't download Xcode 13 from there. I looked at https://developer.apple.com/download/all/ but there I only see a bunch of tools, not Xcode 13 itself.

[image]

Are there other ways to download Xcode 13?

Comment: Ask your manager or the team that does the blocking how to download Xcode so that you can do your job.

Comment: Nice example of "blocking due to security" which _reduces_ security as people are now forced to get the tools they need to do their job elsewhere… with the potential to get an malicious version instead.

Comment: If that's what's going on.  So far, the OP has only said "I want", not "I need and they won't give it to me".  For all we know, he has his personal device plugged into their network.

Comment: @MarcWilson The difference between "I want" and "I need to" might not be obvious to non-native speakers, so let's give the OP the benefit of the doubt :-)

Comment: On the page you have made a screenshot of, you now have Xcode 13 as well - it was added yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

This site: [xcodereleases](https://xcodereleases.com) has a list of all the releases of Xcode. 
The latest available version is right at the top of the page.

Also, it looks like they've updated [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/) since you can now find direct links to download Xcode (I last tested on 27/10/21).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: FYI This requires the user to login or create an account with Apple. A direct download would be more helpful

Comment: The question is not "how to download without having an account with Apple"